# help with Test Class - No Coverage on Trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am coming along slowly with code and think now I am just making lots of mistakes so any guidance will be appreciated. Im sorry if this is a stupid question but I really am trying :(

This is my trigger which takes the  Case.ContactId data and populates Luxury_Agent_ID__c with it where the Contact & The case meet certain criteria:

---

```
trigger HeroIdfromCase on Case (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> luxuryConIds = new Set<Id>(); 

   Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Travel Agent').RecordTypeId;  
    for (Case c: Trigger.new) {

        if( c.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId) 
            // if case record type is 'Travel Agent'
        { 
            if( c.ContactId != null)  {
                // AND if the case contact  field is populated 
                luxuryConIds.add (c.ContactId); {
                    if (c.Subject == 'I would like to become a Small Luxury Hero!') {
                     //AND if the case subject is 'I would like to become a Small Luxury Hero!'


                    }
                }
            }
         List<Contact> ContactsForUpdating = [SELECT Id, Luxury_Agent_ID__c
                                                       FROM Contact
                                                       WHERE Id  IN: LuxuryConIds];
         for (Contact LX: ContactsForUpdating) {
        LX.Luxury_Agent_ID__c = LX.Id;
    }
    update ContactsForUpdating;
```

### }}}

### and this is the Test class so far :

```
@isTest
public  class testHeroIdfromCase {
        static testMethod void TestHeroIdfromCaseTrigger () { 

                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult cfrSchema = Schema.SObjectType.Case;
                Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> CaseRecordTypeInfo = cfrSchema.getRecordTypeInfosByName(); 
Id rtId = CaseRecordTypeInfo.get('Travel Agent').getRecordTypeId();
            { 

                Contact heroCon = [SELECT Id from Contact WHERE SLH_Division__c = 'SLH Travel Agents'];
                    insert heroCon ;

                { 
                      Case  c = new Case () ; 

                                 c.Subject = ('I would like to become a Small Luxury Hero!');
                                 c.RecordTypeId = rtId;
                                 c.ContactId = heroCon.Id;
                                        insert c ;

}
            }
        }
}
```

I am not getting errors but when I run the Test is sais I have 0% code coverage.. please can you advise where I have gone wrong.. I imagine there is a lot to change ?

Thank you in advance  - Iam learning etiqutte on here still too so apologies if I am irritating

Comment: That test should give you at least some coverage. Salesforce sometimes incorrectly reports 0% coverage. Have a look at this answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97314/salesforce-test-coverage-stuck-at-0

Comment: What are all the brackets in your test class for. Is there code missing in your post? If they are conditions, maybe a condition is not being met and thus you never insert the `heroCon`. Please post the complete code if possible. Otherwise the other answers would be where I would check as well

Comment: @eric only because the editor kept it expected brackets... do you think maybe i need to get better at this before asking questions on here? I dont want to annoy everyone

Comment: @LouisaPidcock - All good. Was just asking because the brackets in the test code suggest other code was supposed to be there. Brackets are used for code blocks like (if, for, while, etc) they are not needed otherwise. If there was other code in your test class, it would be needed to give you a concise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem recently but managed to figure it out.

Take a look at my post and answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97314/salesforce-test-coverage-stuck-at-0). It may be that you have a totally different problem, but this is sounds similar to what I had. :)