# Test class for controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller, custom

I am new to salesforce and i am writing a test class for custom controller and it is showing 64% code coverage 
Here is my visual force page in which that controller is used

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Property__c" extensions="propertycontrollerdetail" standardstylesheets="true" showheader="false" sidebar="false" >
    <head>
            <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap,'bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
            <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap,'bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}" />

    </head>
    <body>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

  <div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="navbar-header">
      <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Images, 'Images/RE.jpg')}" width="1340" height="130" />
          </div>

    <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/HomePage?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1">Home</a> 
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Property</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/Property">Detail</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/AgentCreate?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1">Create</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
        <apex:messages />
        <!-- <apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Property__c.label} Edit" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Property__c.Name), 'New Property',Property__c.Name)}"/> -->
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" title="{!$ObjectType.Property__c.label} Edit">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!SaveA}"/>

            </apex:pageblockbuttons>

            <!-- **********   [Record Type : Master ]   **********  -->
            <apex:outputpanel >
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Property__c.Name}"/>
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Property__c.OwnerId}"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Address__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Type__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Status__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Size__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Size_in_sq_ft__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Min_Price__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Max_Price__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Description__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                        <apex:outputlabel value="Location"/>
                        <apex:outputpanel >
                            <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Location__Latitude__s}" required="false"/>
                            <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Location__Longitude__s}" required="false"/>
                        </apex:outputpanel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Property__c.Agent_ID__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>

    </body>

</apex:page>
```

Controller is

```
public with sharing class propertycontrollerdetail {
public Property__c ppo {get; set;}


public propertycontrollerdetail(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
   ppo = (Property__c)controller.getRecord();
}

public pageReference SaveA()
{
    try{
     upsert ppo;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/Property');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;  
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
     system.debug(ex);
     PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/a01/o');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef; 
    }
 }
}
```

And my test class is

```
@isTest
public class TestPropertycontrollerdetail {
    static testMethod void saveA(){

        Property__c pro = new Property__c( seit__Address__c = 'Lalazkhbhjkgar',seit__Description__c='sghj sjgh ',seit__Size__c='10 Marla',seit__Size_in_sq_ft__c='12000',seit__Status__c='Sold',seit__Type__c='Residential');


    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(pro);

    propertycontrollerdetail controller = new propertycontrollerdetail(sc);
        controller.SaveA();
        //add your asserts

    }
    static testMethod void saveA1(){

       Property__c pro = new Property__c();
       ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(pro);
       propertycontrollerdetail controller = new propertycontrollerdetail(sc);
       controller.SaveA();
       //add your asserts
    }
}
```

If any one could guide me or help me with the code i will appreciate it

Comment: turn off store only aggregate code coverage. lots of topics on this here. If you are looking in dev console see this answer: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97314/salesforce-test-coverage-stuck-at-0

Comment: thanks Ratan it worked but it is covering only 21% how i can increase the code coverage

Comment: @Sheheri you need to call `SaveA`  method( i.e. `controller.SaveA()`) and check your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@isTest
public class TestPropertyController{

    static testMethod void saveA(){

        Property__c pro = new Property__c( seit__Address__c = 'Lalazkhbhjkgar',seit__Description__c='sghj sjgh ',seit__Size__c='10 Marla',seit__Size_in_sq_ft__c='12000',seit__Status__c='Sold',seit__Type__c='Residential');
        try
        {
        insert pro;
            System.debug('Insert Successfull');
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(pro);

    propertycontrollerdetail controller = new propertycontrollerdetail(sc);
    controller.SaveA();
    // add your asserts to check expected behavior 
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class propertycontrollerdetail {
public Property__c ppo {get; set;}


    public propertycontrollerdetail(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
       ppo = (Property__c)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public pageReference SaveA()
    {
        try{
         upsert ppo;
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/Property');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
         system.debug(ex);
         PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/a01/o');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef; 
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class TestPropertycontrollerdetail {
    static testMethod void saveA(){

        Property__c pro = new Property__c( seit__Address__c = 'Lalazkhbhjkgar',seit__Description__c='sghj sjgh ',seit__Size__c='10 Marla',seit__Size_in_sq_ft__c='12000',seit__Status__c='Sold',seit__Type__c='Residential');


    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(pro);

    propertycontrollerdetail controller = new propertycontrollerdetail(sc);
        controller.SaveA();
        //add your asserts

    }
    static testMethod void saveA1(){

       Property__c pro = new Property__c();
       ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(pro);
       propertycontrollerdetail controller = new propertycontrollerdetail(sc);
       controller.SaveA();
       //add your asserts
    }

}
```

Comment: its working but code coverage is only 60%

Comment: insert one more Property record by missing any required field, then it goes into catch block. it will increase code coverage

Comment: @Sheheri why you need `throw ex;` inside `SaveA` method?

Comment: I have removed it that now.....

Comment: @Ratan it still not covering code

Comment: @Sheheri in your constructor instead of `ppo = new seit__Property__c();` I believe you need `ppo = (seit__Property__c)controller.getRecord();`

Comment: hey @Sheheri check my edit..

Comment: @Ratan its not covering code greater than 60 % ...i have tried both the true values and false values but code coverage is not increasing

Comment: @Sheheri have you updated teh controller.. check my edit I have updated your controller.

Comment: @Ratan I have updataed the controller but still code coverage is 60%

Comment: @Sheheri refresh page and check. I have tested this in my org 100%. Please add your updated controller and test class in above questions

Comment: @Ratan I have updated the code and now it is 64%covering the code

Comment: @Sheheri pls add your code in above question so I can review.

Comment: @Ratan I have updated the question Please review

Comment: @Sheheri you dont have any required field on `Property__c` ?

Comment: yes i dont have any required field

Comment: Thanks @Ratan The problem is solved now.
The problem was i were not having any required field so when i make the field require it gives me full code coverage.
Ratan Thanks for your cooperation